# How do I parse the Following Date Structure: HHMM/DD?

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I have two dates:

(Hour:Minute/Day)

Both in string format.

**Example 1:**

Main date: "00:10/01"      (01.03.2020 - data available)

Secondary date: "23:45/29"   (29.02.2020 - not available (should be calculated))

```
var mainDate = moment("01.03.2020 00:10");
var secondaryDate = "23:45/29";
```

Output should be: 29.02.2020 - 23:45

**Information I have**

Main date: 01.03.2020 [Date Object / String] (Day, Month, Year, Hour Minute)
Secondary date: "23:45/29" [String] (Hour, Minute, Day)

**Output expected**

It should calculate the complete date, relative to the main day

29.02.2020

**Real Life Example 1**

Scheduled time of departure: 23:45/01    (my system knows that /01 is the 01.01.2020)

Actual time of departure: 00:50/02   (my system doesn't know the date)

Output should be that the aircraft departure time (timestamp) was 02.01.2020 - 00:50

**Real Life Example 2**

Scheduled time of departure: 00:45/01    (my system knows that /01 is the 01.01.2020)

Actual time of departure: 23:50/31   (my system doesn't know the date)

Output should be that the aircraft departure time (timestamp) was 31.12.2019 - 23:50

What could be a function to calculate this?

- NodeJS
- MomentJS

Comment: Do you have any code to share regarding this? It's not clear how your inputs would actually be formatted - is the date/data just one long string or a more complex structure? Seems like it would have to be the latter.

Comment: sorry both are string:    var mainDate = "00:10/01";

Comment: Ok, but where is this extra data (incluing the dates) coming from? e.g. "29.02.2020 - not available (should be calculated)". You can't infer a full date from just a day.

Comment: What did you try? Why make a decision between [tag:node.js] and [tag:momentjs], that doesn't make a lot of sense, are you asking how you could do it purely with either one? Is the day always the month where a user is viewing it? It feels wrong, why not store a full datetime somewhere instead?

Comment: I can fully control the main date. i can access all information (DD.MM.YYYY) but from the secondary date i only get   The Hour:Minute/Days

Comment: Does the "secondary date" have the same yyyy-MM-dd as the "main date"? (Where yyyy represents a four-digit year, MM a month in the range [1, 12], and dd a day in the range appropriate for the month).

Comment: from  the  main date i have everything, from the secondary only the hour, minute, and day number of month, no month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get the date part of the secondary data, you can compare it to the date part of the main date. If the former is in effect before the latter, you know to subtract a month when creating the full secondary date.

```js
function getSecondaryDate(mainDate, secondaryInfo) {
    var baseDate = moment(mainDate, "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm");

    var secParts = secondaryInfo.split("/");
    if (secParts.length != 2) {
        // something is wrong
        alert("Wrong number of parts for secondary date.");
    }
    
    var secDayOfMonth = parseInt(secParts[1]);
    if (isNaN(secDayOfMonth)) {
        // something went wrong
        alert("Could not parse date part of secondary date '" + secDayOfMonth + "'");
    }
    
    var monthInc = 0;
    if (secDayOfMonth > baseDate.date() + 15) {
        monthInc = -1;
    } else if (secDayOfMonth < baseDate.date() - 15) {
        monthInc = 1
    }
    
    var secondaryDate = moment().year(baseDate.year()).month(baseDate.month()).add(monthInc, "month").date(secDayOfMonth);
    if (!secondaryDate.isValid()) {
        // something went wrong
        alert("Failed to construct secondary date.");
    }

    return secondaryDate;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    var mainDate = "01.03.2020 00:10";
    var secondary = "23:45/29";
    
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = getSecondaryDate(mainDate, secondary).format("YYYY-MM-DD") + "<br>" +
                            getSecondaryDate("01.01.2020 00:10", "23:50/31").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<body>
<p id="result"></p>
</body>
```

I'm sure you can see how to add the time on too from `var secTime = secParts[0].split(":");`.

Comment: Thank You! You are right!   I have following problem with the code:

Comment: When i run this: getSecondaryDate("21.02.2021 06:56", "06:56/21")   i get this result:  21.01.2021 06:56

Comment: I fixed this with:  changing from secDayOfMonth > baseDate.day()   -> secDayOfMonth > baseDate.date()

Comment: But with both solutions i have a problem with 31.12.2020 | 05:00/01  it gives me 01.12.2020 not 01.01.2021

Comment: @TobiasJung I had an error with using `.day()` instead of `.date()` (IMO they should have used better names) and I've added an `if else` clause. Please try the updated code.